# Is there a way to limit map loads by user IP in Mapbox?

Tags: dictionary, mapbox

Mapbox offers 50,000 free map loads per month, but after that, the cost per every additional 1,000 loads is a few dollars each per month, which can become pricy.

Does anyone know if there's a way to restrict map loads by user IP within Mapbox settings, so you can set defacto limits on individual users?

Or is this something I should attempt to do on my end?  Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can add URL restrictions see https://docs.mapbox.com/accounts/overview/tokens/#url-restrictions to limit which sites are permitted to use your access token.

For sites where you have a user sesssion you can issue temporary Mapbox Access Tokens via https://docs.mapbox.com/api/accounts/#create-a-temporary-token for only the user sessions you like, so you could check the users IP address and then based on that issue a temporary token or not.